# Sorting and Selection- Slower Order By Clause and Distinct Operation in Neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to return the top 5 scorers using the ORDER BY clause in Neo4j. Unfortunately, since the no of records is more than 500K, the sorting operation is much slower than expected.

Is there any other way that I can return the top 5 Scorers faster within few seconds.

My Query:

```
        WITH [23,232,143,843,34,35,980,529,489,378] AS sellers,
        ['a26','762','e2c','6b57','369','aa10','6ba5','b9a','aa03','d3fd'] AS buyers

        MATCH (org:Organization{org_guid:'5de2c1'})-[:EMP_BY]-(org_member:Person)

        MATCH (seller:Person) WHERE seller.person_guid IN sellers
        MATCH (buyer:Person) WHERE buyer.person_guid IN buyers

        MATCH (seller)-[:TEAM_MEMBER]-(sellerteam:Person)

        OPTIONAL MATCH (org_member)-[p:P2P]-(buyer)-[q:EMP_BY]-(:Organization)
        WITH CASE
             WHEN (p IS NOT NULL AND q is NOT NULL AND org_member IN collect(sellers)) THEN p.strength*q.influence
             WHEN (p IS NOT NULL AND q is NOT NULL AND org_member IN collect(sellerteam)) THEN p.strength*q.influence*0.6
             WHEN (p IS NOT NULL AND q is NOT NULL ) THEN p.strength*q.influence*0.3
             WHEN (p IS NOT NULL AND q is NULL AND org_member IN collect(sellers)) THEN p.strength*0.7
             WHEN (p IS NOT NULL AND q is NULL AND org_member IN collect(sellerteam)) THEN p.strength*0.7*0.6
             WHEN (p IS NOT NULL AND q is NULL ) THEN p.strength*0.7*0.3
             WHEN (p IS NULL AND q IS NOT NULL) THEN q.influence*0.3
             ELSE 0
          END AS score,buyer
        RETURN DISTINCT buyer.person_guid,score ORDER BY score LIMIT 5
```

With order by clause:

```
Returned 5 rows in 345255 ms.
```

Without order by clause:

```
Returned 5 rows in 148240 ms.
```

Profile Images:
[image]

[image]

[image]
Statistics:

```
org_mermber: 45k
team_member: 700+
sellers    : 10
Buyers     : 10
```

Since Each buyer will have score, I am using DISTINCT and Order By . How can I speed up this query?

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint on :Person(person_guid), and :Organization(org_guid)? Also, could you do a PROFILE of this query, expand all elements of the profile, and paste an image of it in your description?

Comment: Yes I have index on both.

Comment: I'm curious about your entire first match and the entirety of your seller-to-team_member match, as you don't seem to be using any of the variables involved later in your query. Is there a reason to keep these in?

Comment: Yes, In the case statement. If the seller is in team_member then then score *0.8, else seller is in org_member then score*0.5 and seller is not in both then score*1.(And a small change in the query)

Comment: I just not added all the cases in the CASE statement. If it works well then i will add all cases and test

Comment: I think you better add your complete query, it's hard to see how parts of the query relate to each other without it. For example, as far as I can tell there's nothing connecting a seller to your buyer query, so in the query you presented, it's useless. Without context, it's hard to give good advice on how to optimize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136434/discussion-between-jack-daniel-and-inversefalcon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the full query.

For one, you're doing an awful lot of collects many of them per-row in your CASE statement. It's a good idea to do your collects earlier in your query, preferably before the parts of your query which generate many rows.

We can also reorder some parts of your query for better performance.

Also, it looks like there are about 43,396 persons in the organization, so rather than collect those for use in the IN check later, it may be faster to check for the existence of a relationship to the organization later in the query.

Let's see if this cleans things up. It's a big complicated query, so we may have to troubleshoot for mistakes, but it should get around the bottleneck in your original query with expansion to org_members.

```
    // first let's get collections of all sellers and sellerteams

    WITH [23,232,143,843,34,35,980,529,489,378] AS sellers
    MATCH (seller:Person) WHERE seller.person_guid IN sellers

    // COLLECT then UNWIND so we keep all sellers in a collection
    // even as we match seller to seller_team
    WITH COLLECT(seller) as sellers
    UNWIND sellers as seller
    MATCH (seller)-[:TEAM_MEMBER]-(seller_team:Person)

    WITH sellers, COLLECT(seller_team) as sellerteam
    // since all elements are collections, only 1 row built up

    MATCH (org:Organization{org_guid:'5de2c1'})
    WITH sellers, sellerteam, org,
     ['a26','762','e2c','6b57','369','aa10','6ba5','b9a','aa03','d3fd'] AS buyers
    MATCH (buyer:Person) WHERE buyer.person_guid IN buyers

    WITH sellers, sellerteam, org, buyer

    // let's break the big optional match in 2
    OPTIONAL MATCH (buyer)-[q:EMP_BY]-(:Organization)

    // save q.influence (with a default); save whether q is null for later
    WITH sellers, sellerteam, org, buyer, COALESCE(q.influence, 0.7) as qInfluence, q is NULL as qNull

    // other half of the big optional match, should be less expensive
    // to ensure org_member is an organization member this way
    OPTIONAL MATCH (org_member)-[p:P2P]-(buyer)
    WHERE (org_member)-[:EMP_BY]-(org)

    // save p.strength (with a default); save whether p is null for later
    // save whether org_member is a seller or on the sellerteam
    WITH sellers, sellerteam, buyer, qInfluence, qNull, COALESCE(p.strength, 1.0) as pStrength, 
    p is NULL as pNull, org_member in sellers as sellerMember, org_member in sellerteam as teamMember

    WITH buyer, qInfluence, pStrength, 
      CASE WHEN pNull and qNull THEN 0.0
           WHEN sellerMember    THEN 1.0
           WHEN teamMember      THEN 0.6 
                                ELSE 0.3
      END as memberMultiplier
    WITH DISTINCT buyer, qInfluence * pStrength * memberMultiplier as score
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
    RETURN buyer.person_guid, score
```